# How to serialise any given class containing circular references

Tags: java, serialization, gson, stack-overflow, circular-reference

I try to analyse Projects and their test cases to see what methods, in the test methods, actually change values of the fields of the tested classes (objects). I am using Gson to serialise these objects, to compare the resulting String before and after the execution of the test.

Here I ran into a `StackOverflowError` because some objects have circular-references. I searched for a result, but all I found was answers for serialisation where the object to serialise is known and accessible (what I have not, since I dynamically assign the different classes coming from the project to analyse).

Does someone know how to implement such a general serialiser which can handle these circular-references.

My ideas were the following:

1. Use an exclusion strategy in `Variable.java` (below), but since I
   don't    know the classes, I don't know how to implement this
   strategy.
2. Since I don't have to deserialise, I could simply set a recursion
   depth limit, but I found no way to implement this with Gson.
3. Maybe there could be a good way to solve this in the
   `JsonSerializer`    but there again, I don't know how.

`ClassTypeAdapter.java` (a simple adapter to serialise all Objects)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class ClassTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Class<?>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Class<?> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.getName());
    }
}
```

`Variable.java`

```
public abstract class Variable {

    private String value; // Json string
    private STATE state;

    public Variable(Object value) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
//              .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
//                  public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) { return false; }
//                  public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) { return false; } })
                .registerTypeAdapter(Class.class, new ClassTypeAdapter())
                .create();
        this.value = gson.toJson(value);
        this.state = STATE.NOT_CHANGED;
    }

    public void Update(String newValue) {
        if (!this.value.equals(newValue)) this.state = STATE.CHANGED;
        this.value = newValue;
    }
}
public enum STATE { CHANGED, NOT_CHANGED; }
```

**EDIT: Questions**
Or is there any alternative to Gson for serialisation, which makes it easier to serialise unknown circular-references?
Has someone an idea on how to use DataTransferObject pattern on objects defined at runtime to make it more Gson-friendly?

Comment: Not sure, but this one might be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213747/gson-serialize-circular-references-using-stubs/41304011#41304011

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv: thank you for your answer. But I have no influence on the classes I want to serialise, and therefore, I can't add an Id to each object.

Comment: Did you take a look at the Data Transfer Object pattern to convert your objects to Gson-friendly form?

Comment: I think, this is the most simplified and systematic example for a custom serializer: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/  I implemented my own from there. You can just NOT addProperty() for the circular field.

Comment: @pulp_fiction: I do not know the objects until runtime, so I can't create the serialiser described in this article.